# I disabled power management but the screen gets locked after 5 minutes

Tags: xubuntu, power-management

I went to the Power Manager settings and set the timeout to "Never" but the screen keeps locking after 5 minutes of inactivity. I'm using Xubuntu 20.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need also to go to Settings -> Screensaver and disable it there too.

There is a screen blocking tab.